# I try to show a VAR in the VIEW,but it doesn't show NOTHING

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a Controller,a Model and a View for my ASP.NET MVC 4 website...
But,when I try to SHOW my ViewBag called GroupId,it is not in my view!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AIO___Desafio_Interno_de_Inteligências.Models;

namespace AIO___Desafio_Interno_de_Inteligências.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Login/

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            var detail = new Details()
            {
                GroupId = 23,
                GroupPassword = "280phcdd12",
            };
            return View();
            ViewBag.GroupId = detail.GroupId;
            ViewBag.GroupPassword = detail.GroupPassword;
        }

    }
}
```

And ,in my VIEW CODE:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

<p>@ViewBag.GroupId</p>
<p>@ViewBag.GroupPassword</p>
```

But,what I get is this:

[Just my default CSS,and these codes,as H1 and P... But the ViewBag.{...} is not there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJTdm.png)

[EDIT]

My MODELS page (Details.cs):

```
namespace AIO___Desafio_Interno_de_Inteligências.Models
{
    public class Details
    {
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public string GroupPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are returning before assigning to the `ViewBag`

Comment: Your method ends as soon as you `return`. In other words, `return` should be the last statement.

Comment: Your IDE should be warning your about those two lines after the `return`.  Dont ignore the warnings...

Answer (score 1):

Your controller method should be like this

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    var detail = new Details()
    {
        GroupId = 23,
        GroupPassword = "280phcdd12",
    };

    ViewBag.GroupId = detail.GroupId;
    ViewBag.GroupPassword = detail.GroupPassword;

    return View();
}
```

Set your ViewBag data before returning your view